# Parsing a tuple like string with python

Tags: python, regex

I have a tuple like string line like:

```
("a",10,4,"abc")
```

I would like to parse it to contain each item in a string list:

```
ans = [a, 10, 4, abc]
```

In the example, I achieve easily it splitting the string line with comma.

However, a string item in the string line might have commas and double quotations, like

```
("abc",10,-4,"abc"","d,ef")
```

I would like get the string list.

```
ans = [abc, 10, -4, abc", d,ef]
```

Does anyone have a good idea to achieve it with Python?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is `ans = [a, 10, 4, abc]`? Specifically, what is the `a` and `abc`?

Comment: Double quotes in a string must be escaped if the string is also enclosed by double quotes, i.e. `"abc\""`. Likewise for single quotes.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. You seem to describe something to do with splitting. Please show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is encapsulate with double qoutes & you are using a `"` in it. so need to use the escape character `\` to represent that it is a character.

Try this code !

```
import ast

print(list(ast.literal_eval('("abc",10,-4,"abc\\"","d,ef")')))
```

**Output :**

```
['abc', 10, -4, 'abc"', 'd,ef']
```